# Kotlin breakpoints in IntelliJ IDEA: Putting breakpoints in getters of data class

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Is it possible to put breakpoints in the getter methods of data classes in Kotlin code in IntelliJ IDEA?

My data class is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class MyResponse(
        val location: String,
        val expiresIn: Int?,
        val tokenType: String?,
        val state: String?) : Response
```

I am debugging a complex app by putting breakpoints in my kotlin app. I would like to put breakpoints to know when another piece of code tries to read the members of my MyResponse class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you put a breakpoint on `val` line, then right-click on a breakpoint and tick "Watch field access" you can get what you want.